# Calculate a ratio using SQL incorporating lag values

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table like this

[image]

For each day, I need to calculate the ratio of (sum of val for that day when cat=4) / (sum of val for the previous day when cat=3).

Could you tell me how to calculate that?

I can calculate the numerator and denominator separately like this:

```
select Date, sum(val) as bal1 from performance  
       where cat=4 group by Date 

select Date, sum(val) as bal2 from performance  
       where cat=3 group by Date
```

But I am not sure how to combine those to get the ratio like I mentioned above. May be I need to join the two results by Date.

Any guidance would be highly appreciate.

Comment: Which dbms are you using: MySQL or SQLLite? Also, posting *images* of data samples (instead of plain text) makes it harder for others to help because they can't test potential queries - not without first re-typing all of the sample data.  Posting data samples as text - or better yet in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) format - makes it much easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine aggregation with `LAG()` window function:

```
SELECT Date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN cat = 4 THEN val END) /
       LAG(SUM(CASE WHEN cat = 3 THEN val END)) OVER (ORDER BY Date) ratio  
FROM performance
GROUP BY Date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a10844441d17298e752b58433f3be5d7).

Comment: If possible, could you tell me an online resource that I can follow to learn these kind of SQL operations? Thank you very much!!

Comment: @student_R123 for SQLite I would suggest https://www.sqlitetutorial.net and https://database.guide/category/dbms/rdbms/sqlite/ and the official documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/index.html

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `LAG()` as follows:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(cat) OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Date) lag_cat,
              LAG(val) OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Date) lag_val
    FROM performance
)

SELECT
    Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cat = 4 THEN val ELSE 0 END) /
    SUM(CASE WHEN lag_cat = 3 THEN lag_val ELSE 0 END) AS ratio
FROM cte
GROUP BY Date;
```